# Microsoft visual basic 6 warning in relation to a newer version of tlb

Tags: vb6, tlb, visual-studio-6

I am working with a very large code base composed of several groups of projects in vb6.

Every time I open the group project I'm prompted with several of these pop-up messages asking me if I want to upgrade to the new version of the .tlb

[image]

I know these get created when we register the dlls but I'm not sure how to get rid of these messages, I usually just click yet to all of them and the project loads fine. Is there any way I can remove these or set the version to load as the new 21.1 version by default?

Comment: Usually if you save the VBP after clicking YES, the next time it won't show the message. You will see in the VBP the version # will get changed for that reference. Does this not happen?

Comment: for some reason, it's not saving it for me. I will check, maybe it's because we use source safe as source control, and I'm not sure we check the group project solution in and out, we might just check the different projects themselves. in this case, this group solution would never be saved.  I will try that later on and let you know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are using a group, then VB6 may be seeing a conflict between the bincomp DLL of the project in the group, and some other copy of that DLL which is registered. I would try regsvr32 /u on the DLL and then load the group again, see if that helps. In cases like this I've seen before, that often doesn't work, so I've ended up going through the registry manually to remove the GUID for that project; hope that's not needed!